# Как сделать, чтобы консоль в гугл хроме не открывалась в новой вкладке?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Всем привет, когда открываю консоль в гугл хроме нажимаю кнопку правой мыши и посмотреть код, у меня всегда консоль открывается в новой вкладке не могу найти в инструментах разработчика чтобы это исправить и открывалась как обычно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: картинок много, смысла мало, открывалась как обычно это как?

Comment: Нажимаю правой кнопкой посмотреть код и у меня открывается новая вкладка, а должна просто открыться консоль

Comment: открытие `view-source:https://...`  — это и есть как обычно, если нужно глянуть разметку нужно нажимать `F12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вы хотите, чтобы консоль DevTools была прикреплена к странице, а не открывалась в новом окне. Расположение DevTools можно изменить. Откройте настройки DevTools с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу и выберите раположение, которое вам нравится.

[image: Настройка расположения DevTools]

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/customize/#placement